Calendar arbitrage for European Swaptions
I was wondering if for interest rate European Swaptions we had the same calendar arbitrage condition that holds for Equity or FX options.
I’m a bit confused since when applying Jensen inequality we need to be in the same measure for the tower property but two swaps with different expiries are not martingale in the same measure.

In equity / FX the underlying is not a term structure, it's a single price process. With swaptions the underlying instruments are different assets - a 10 yr swap starting in 5 years is not the same asset as a 10 yr swap starting in 1 yr or a 5 yr swap starting in 5y. So it's not clear to me what you are looking for / at when you discuss calendar arbitrage?

You can however check for skew arbitrage for a specific swap. See also this question and answer(s): https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/64100/free-arbitrage-conditions-in-atm-swaption-surfaces
